# first time customer free shipping on your first order

Tags: magento

My Question:
How to logical and programmatic develop for this requirement.
My requirement that : I need free shipping on customer first order. I have not any used coupon code or discount.
I have directly set free shipping when customer sign up and place order.

Comment: You cant fulfil your requirement in this way. You need to do a lot.

Comment: Err... what? What can we help you? What is the question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create one custom shipping methods then add my custom code for above requirment.

Shipping methods URL: following this url

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

then added my code in carrier.php file like below.

$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

```
 if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {

            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
            //echo '<pre>';
            //print_r(get_class_methods($customer));
            $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer->getId());

            if (!$orders->getSize())
            { 
                $result->append($this->_getFreeRate());
                return $result;
            }


        }else{

            if ($expressAvailable) {
            $result->append($this->_getExpressRate());
            }
            $result->append($this->_getStandardRate());
            return $result;
            }
```